# how to not let other div overlap my nav bar

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I cant seem to figure out how to overlap my nav bar so that it will always be on full display when scrolling. The code is given below. Please help me as  i am lost for a few days. I've fixed the navagation bar by using position:fixed. i dont know whether my position of div element is wrong or there is something that i should ve known earlier before making a fixed navigation bar.

`

```css
body{
  background-image:url('https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Blue-icy-ocean-wallpaper-HD.jpg');

  
}
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#maindiv{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}

#navdiv ul{
  width:100%;
  height:80px; 
  background-color:#000916;
  line-height:80px;
    position:fixed;
}
#navdiv ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
}
#navdiv ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
}
#navdiv ul a:hover{
  background:#000948;
  transition: all 0.40s;
}
#navdiv h1{
  color:white;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#about{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#000916;
  border-radius:30px;;
}
#about p{
  color:white;
}
#left-text1{
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.resize{
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="maindiv">
      <div id = "navdiv">
        <ul>
          <h1>Danial</h1>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="left-text1">Welcome to my Site<br>I am a front-end web developer who loves to cooperate and involve in projects to either earned money or earned experience</p>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="resize"src="https://www.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/digi/casual-man-standing-free-vector-17.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`

Comment: just add `z-index:99999;` to `#navdiv ul` class so it would always be in front

Comment: dude that legit just solve my problem, Thanks!

Comment: mark my answer as soultion then,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
  background-image:url('https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Blue-icy-ocean-wallpaper-HD.jpg');

  
}
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#maindiv{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}

#navdiv ul{
  width:100%;
  height:80px; 
  background-color:#000916;
  line-height:80px;
    position:fixed;
  /* you can set who you want to be infront by the z-index prop */
  z-index:99999;
}
#navdiv ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
}
#navdiv ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
}
#navdiv ul a:hover{
  background:#000948;
  transition: all 0.40s;
}
#navdiv h1{
  color:white;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#about{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#000916;
  border-radius:30px;;
}
#about p{
  color:white;
}
#left-text1{
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.resize{
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="maindiv">
      <div id = "navdiv">
        <ul>
          <h1>Danial</h1>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="linkref">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="left-text1">Welcome to my Site<br>I am a front-end web developer who loves to cooperate and involve in projects to either earned money or earned experience</p>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="resize"src="https://www.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/digi/casual-man-standing-free-vector-17.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```